# Math numbers rendered as FaceTime phone number

Tags: bug, mathjax, ios

In a recent answer of mine, I noticed that a chain of equations renders correctly on my laptop but incorrectly on iPad and iPhone. The iPad/iPhone treats a particular number as if it is a phone number. It then inserts a FaceTime link which messes up the LaTeX/MathJax rendering, making the answer unreadable. The number is $1664474849$, which appears in the numerator calculation of $q(5)$ here:

[Coin Flip Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719946/coin-flip-problem/3719998#3719998)

I could likely play around with different ways to type my equation, but I leave it as-is so you can see the issue for yourself (if you view from iPad/iPhone).

**Question/comment:** This seems to be a larger issue that could affect many questions/answers. It may already be affecting one of your own questions/answers and you do not know it because you only use a laptop. It may also annoy people who happen to have those phone numbers. Can something be done to fix the general problem?

---

Edit: I notice that for **this** question, the number I typed above is rendered without the incorrect FaceTime link even on iPad...I don’t know why. Perhaps the bug only occurs when the number is in `\begin{align}` equations rather than dollar signs.

Comment: I would guess that this is an issue with Safari / whatever browser you are using on your tablet or phone---these devices are built to detect phone numbers.  I doubt that this is an issue with Math SE, or one which the software here can do very much about.

Comment: Here is an older post on this meta: [MathJax fails when rendering long digit strings on iOS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4252). On [meta.se] I only found this one, but it is not about MathJax: [Stop Safari-Mobile from converting 7 digits numbers into “tel” format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243640). (Maybe someone else might have better luck when searching.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@XanderHenderson is right, this is a built-in feature of iOS; since the number of people looking for pizza delivery with their iPhone dwarfs the number of people doing Mathematics with it by a few orders of magnitude, they deemed it useful to convert everything that looks like a phone number into a phone link. The feature does take the context of the number into account, which is why not all 10 digits numbers starting with a 1 are 'linkified', but apparently it's not that smart.
The bad news is that you [can't turn it off as a user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/350415/121968) but it'll probably come in handy outside your professional life.

A workaround might be to insert a `\hspace{0pt}` somewhere in the number, as I did [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31953/228959) in the Sandbox (sorry for the edit to your post, that happens when you're editing three posts at once...). It renders correctly for me on iOS, and even copy/pasting works fine. I'm not sure if there are any other side effects.

Since 1664474849 is a typical US phone number format, one might wonder if changing the language/region setting would help, but my iPhone (language: English/United States, region: the Netherlands) detects both those and a more typical Dutch phone number like 0612345678.

Comment: Thanks, I will likely implement your \hspace{0pt} solution in a few days after any residual answers to this question may come in.